# input fields in vuetify or css

Tags: css, vuetify.js

[image]

How can I do the thing in the picture in vuetify or css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [vuetify documention](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icons), you can prepend and append icons to input fields.

> You can add icons to the text field with prepend-icon, append-icon and append-outer-icon props.

Vuetify uses [material design icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/), so the code to accomplish your desired design is the following:

```
<template>
    <v-text-field
        solo
        label="Name"
        prepend-inner-icon="mdi-account"
    ></v-text-field>
</template>
```

Or you can achieve even more modern look, by fixing the placeholder as a label in the input's outline, when the input is focused. The code to do so is:

```
<template>
    <v-text-field
        outlined
        label="Name"
        prepend-inner-icon="mdi-account"
    ></v-text-field>
</template>
```

Comment: when i tryed this with the same input field i get the icon outside the fields

Comment: I just edited my answer, please try now, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to have the icon inside the text field borders, these two are for you:

1. `prepend-inner-icon` prop for icon - [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props-prepend-inner-icon)

```html
<v-text-field prepend-inner-icon="account">
</v-text-field>
```

2. `prepend-inner` slot for custom image - [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#slots-prepend-inner)

```html
<v-text-field>
     <template v-slot:prepend-inner>
         <img src="/account.svg" height="20">
      </template>
</v-text-field>
```

[Here's](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icons) a nifty demo as well for icons.